# I'm looping a prompt to ask the user to enter a integer and sort it using bubblesort method and printing it in a output

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm looping a prompt to ask the user to enter an integer and sort it using bubble sort method and printing it in an output.  I need a button when clicked to ask the user to enter 4 numbers and output them as integers and be sorted and printed in the HTML page from the empty array I presented.  I just need help understanding how to set it up because I have been trying and not getting it down right.  Not an avid coder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>User Input, Sort and Find!</title>

<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Enter 4 numbers user!</h2>
<p id="myprint"></p>

<button onclick="userInput()">Input your Numbers!</button>
<button onclick="searchInput()">Find an inputed number in your array </button>
<script>
var numbers = [];

function userInput() {
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   numbers.push(prompt("Enter a number 1 at a time, from 1-9 until prompts ask you 4 times:"));
   if (numbers[i] = NaN) {
   alert("Enter a number!");
    } else if( numbers[i] % 1 == 0) {
   alert("Enter a whole number!")
        }
    }
}
//Sort the array and print numbers in inner html
    function bubbleSort(numbers) {  
    var length = numbers.length;
    for (var i = (length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var j = (length - i); j > 0; j--) {
            if (numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]) {
                var nmbr = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
                numbers[j - 1] = nmbr;
            }
        }
    }
}
function searchInput() {

}
document.getElementById("myprint").innerHTML = "Your numbers are" + numbers;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is your issue. please be more specific

Comment: My issue is getting a forloop to prompt a question to ask the user to input numbers and store them into an empty array which is var numbers[]; Then after that happens it needs to be sorted and printed into p= id"myprint"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at your code and there seems to be a few errors I can spot.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       numbers.push(prompt("Enter a number 1 at a time, from 1-9 until prompts    ask you 4 times:"));
       if (numbers[i] = NaN) { // this is the wrong logic ...
       alert("Enter a number!");
        } else if( numbers[i] % 1 == 0) { **// this is not correct because your basically saying every integer number is not a whole number.**
       alert("Enter a whole number!")
            }
        }
    }
```

The algorithm I have provided below for your loop that prompts the user considers all the scenarios that could go wrong and deal with them, at least this should give you a good base to move onto whatever you wish to do with it next.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   var num = prompt("Enter a number 1 at a time, from 1-9 until prompts ask you 4 times:");
   if (isNaN(num)) {
     alert("Enter a number!");
    --i; // reset the counter for amount of numbers entered
   }
   if( !isNaN(num)) {
      if( num % 1 != 0){
         alert("Enter a whole number!")
         --i;  // reset the counter for amount of numbers entered
      }else{
         numbers.push(num);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That helps the forloop part, but how do I sort it and print it into the numbers array without it being a string and becoming an integer instead? The function below that one was the sort method, but I don't know how exactly to interpret it to sort the function above it with the forloop.

Comment: i will update this post in a few mins to try and cover what you wish to be helped with

Comment: Thank you man.  If you know any links that can help explain my issues it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i have updated the loop that prompts the user for input and now you can just proceed with you bubble sort algorithm and then you can do what you wish with it.